# Sync node Ethereum

Tags: synchronization, ethereum, nodes

today I come to you because I have been synchronizing an eth node since September and it has taken an abnormally long time. Here is my problem: I came here to find out if someone can help me finish the sync of my eth node. It's been 1 month that the sync remains at 100% but never ends. Can anyone help me? Here is the information needed to see where I made my mistake :

sudo apt update

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ethereum

Connecting to Consensus Clients
mkdir prysm && cd prysm

curl https raw.githubusercontent.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/master/prysm.sh --output prysm.sh && chmod +x prysm.sh

./prysm.sh beacon-chain generate-auth-secret

starting geth server/node
geth --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin --authrpc.jwtsecret /root/prysm/jwt.hex

starting Consensus Client
./prysm.sh beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http localhost:8551/ --jwt-secret=/root/prysm/jwt.hex --suggested-fee-recipient=x0MyPK

LOG GETH :
`INFO [01-12|10:53:34.450] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=367.45GiB headers=18,990,345@6.96GiB bodies=18,990,244@243.78GiB receipts=18,990,244@116.71GiB eta=17m27.201s`

PRYSM LOG:
`[2024-01-12 10:53:49]  INFO blockchain: Synced new block block=0x75f04bd1... epoch=255814 finalizedEpoch=255812 finalizedRoot=0x67d5e1d3... slot=8186067 [2024-01-12 10:53:49]  INFO blockchain: Finished applying state transition attestations=128 payloadHash=0xa741fe909670 slot=8186067 syncBitsCount=494 txCount=126 [2024-01-12 10:53:56]  INFO p2p: Peer summary activePeers=40 inbound=36 outbound=4 [2024-01-12 10:54:01]  INFO blockchain: Called new payload with optimistic block payloadBlockHash=0x2e5a22b7d8a6 slot=8186068`

Thank you very much if you can help me

Comment: When you say "Sync remains at 100%" what do you mean? The node is never "fully synced" as new blocks are produced every minute.

Comment: Yes absolutely, there are still 15 minutes of data left before the end of the sync which means that the node cannot be used because I need to have access to the mempool for my tx analysis tool in time real

Comment: 15 minutes feels a long. There should be a delay of couple of minutes. If you just want to monitor mempool real-time (i.e. pending transactions) there are specialised solutions MEV is using.

Comment: What solutions do you recommend?

Comment: Same here, 100% synced, eta=1 minutes, eth.syncing.currentBlock is ~1 hour away from the latest.